# Is tf.layers.dense a single layer?

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network

If I just use a single layer like this:

```
layer = tf.layers.dense(tf_x, 1, tf.nn.relu)
```

Is this just a single layer with a single node?

Or is it actually a set of layers (input, hidden, output) with 1 node? My network seemed to work properly with just 1 layer, so I was curious about the setup.

Consequently, does this setup below have 2 hidden layers (are `layer1` and `layer2` here both hidden layers)? Or actually just 1 (just `layer 1`)?

```
layer1 = tf.layers.dense(tf_x, 10, tf.nn.relu)
layer2 = tf.layers.dense(layer1, 1, tf.nn.relu)
```

`tf_x` is my input features tensor.

Comment: As to the second part of your question, layer1 would be called a hidden layer and layer2 would be the output layer. In order to investigate what the graph look like try loading your graph in tensorboard.

Comment: This is how I think I understand it, too. But it's different from what @ChristianFei says in the answer below. Your answer would mean, that in the first part, the `layer` would be an hidden layer and an output layer at the same time? Or is just an output layer?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`tf.layers.dense` adds a single layer to your network. The second argument is the number of neurons/nodes of the layer. For example:

```
# no hidden layers, dimension output layer = 1
output = tf.layers.dense(tf_x, 1, tf.nn.relu)

# one hidden layer, dimension hidden layer = 10,  dimension output layer = 1
hidden = tf.layers.dense(tf_x, 10, tf.nn.relu)
output = tf.layers.dense(hidden, 1, tf.nn.relu)
```

> My network seemed to work properly with just 1 layer, so I was curious about the setup.

That is possible, for some tasks you will get decent results without hidden layers.

Answer (score 3):

`tf.layers.dense` (`tf.compat.v1.layers.dense`) is only one layer with a amount of nodes. You can check on TensorFlow web site about [tf.layers.dense (tf.compat.v1.layers.dense)](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/compat/v1/layers/dense)

```
layer1 = tf.layers.dense(inputs=pool2_flat, units=1024, activation=tf.nn.relu)
layer2 = tf.layers.dense(inputs=layer1, units=1024, activation=tf.nn.relu)
```

Comment: Does your setup now have one hidden layer or two? If its just tf.layer.dense is just one layer, the correct answer is: one hidden layer, or?

Comment: input from previous Layer(pool2_flat).
Hidden layer, 1024 nodes.
Hidden layer, 1024 nodes.

So there are 2 hidden layer with each 1024 nodes

Comment: I don't get it. I have learned that the layers of a neural network are setup like this: http://cs231n.github.io/assets/nn1/neural_net2.jpeg . Isn't `layer2` in this case the "output layer"?

Comment: Yes, you can call the last fullyconnected layer also output layer. Output layer is general the lastlayer with fits the tensors to an readable output. This means if your hidden layer has 1024 nodes and you want a to merge it on an output 0 or 1, your output layer will have 2 nodes.