# What is the correct explanation for tf.dense?

Tags: tensorflow, tf.keras

I am using a tutorial to learn RNN. 
As shown in the image below, it has used tf.dense and given an explanation which I cannot understand.

(As a newbie to stackoverflow, I cannot insert images, hence the link)

The documentation at tensorflow.org also does not help much and it is so bad for a beginner like me that I've given a 1-star rating. It says the following (which does not make sense to me)

[The explanation at tensorflow.org](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cjFv5.png)

Can someone kindly explain it to me. Thank you

[Excerpt from the tutorial I am using to learn.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tGIYM.png)

Comment: SO is not a discussion forum. If you have any queries about code, please post it here.

Comment: This is actually my query? I want to understand the meaning of mentioned line of code and not discuss about its benefits or shortcoming !!!!

Comment: Read up on ANNs before using Tensorflow.

Comment: Instead of making screenshots of text, you can put it as text in a quote block (prefixed with `>`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As described in the link below

> **tf.layers.dense** adds a single layer to a network.

Read the answer in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45693020/is-tf-layers-dense-a-single-layer).